# jQuery: Find nextUntil() any heading element

Tags: jquery, nextuntil

I am trying to find all the contents until the next heading title. Heading title could be **h2, h3, h4, h5 or even h6.** That said, in between main and the heading it could have many other elements or a single element so counting them until the next heading is not an option.

How could I achieve this?

This is my current method of which finds up **ONLY** until h4

```
$("main").parent().nextUntil("h4").each(function(){
   console.log($(this).html())               
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [multiple-selecters](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) in [nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil) like,

```
$("main").parent().nextUntil("h2,h3,h4,h5,h6").each(function(){
   console.log($(this).html())               
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [header](http://api.jquery.com/header-selector/) selector

```
$("main").parent().nextUntil(":header").each(function(){
   console.log($(this).html())               
})
```

Comment: This will be more better and generic approach